# Support an hypotesis with significance level $\alpha = 0.05$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Considerate the follow data about voting intention for $1000$ couples. The variables $X_{1}
,X_{2} $ represent the women and men respectively, and $0$ represent voting for the coalition party and $1$ for the opssition party.

|  | $X_{1}= 0$ | $X_{1}=1$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $X_{2}=0$ | $245$ | $170$ |
| $X_{2}=1$ | $218$ | $367$ |

1. Calculate the oddsratio $\hat{R}$
2. If the size of the sample grows to $\infty$, the distribution of $\log(\hat{R})$ converges to a normal with expected value $\log(R)$ (I think my teacher wanted to write $\hat{R}$), the true log-oddratio of the underlying distribution and variances,
   $$\frac{1}{n_{0,0}}+ \frac{1}{n_{0,1}}+\frac{1}{n_{1,0}}+\frac{1}{n_{1,1}}$$

where $n_{i,j}$ is the observations with $X_{1}=i$ and $X_{2}=j$.

Do you support the hypotesis that men and women vote independently each other with significance level $\alpha = 0.05$?

For 1 we have that $\hat{R}=2.4226$.

For 2, under $H_{0}$ (i.e women and men vote independently each other) we have that the oddratio is $1$,son $\log(R)=0$ and the distribution of $\log(\hat{R})\rightarrow N(0, \frac{1}{n_{0,0}}+ \frac{1}{n_{0,1}}+\frac{1}{n_{1,0}}+\frac{1}{n_{1,1}})$.

But, because $\hat{R}=1$ then $n_{0,0}=n_{0,1}$ and $n_{1,0}=n_{1,1}$, so

$$\log(\hat{R})\rightarrow N\left(0, \frac{2}{n_{0,0}}+\frac{2}{n_{1,1}}\right)$$

I don't know what else to do

Comment: Since your test is two tailed your $p-$value seems to be $$\mathbb{P}\Bigg(\hat{R}\in\Big(0,{1 \over 2.4226}\Big]\cup [2.4226,\infty)\Bigg)$$ Do you know how to compute this probability?

Comment: @MatthewPilling no, I don't know, in class we usually aprroximate by the Central Limit to a standar Normal and then find the probability, but I'm not sure...

Comment: @MatthewPilling  I got that $\mathbb{P} (In(\hat{r})\ge \ln (2.4226)) = 1- \Phi(\frac{2.4226}{\sigma})$ where $\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{2}{n_{0,0}}+\frac{2}{n_{1,1}}}$, is this okay? or Am I losing something?

Comment: I think you meant to put **$\ln(2.4226)$** into $\Phi$. Also, your calculation only includes the right tailed area, but your test is two tailed. You should multiply your answer by $2$ to get your $p-$value

Comment: @MatthewPilling  yes, I mean it, my only question is that with this result I have to compute $\sigma$ because we want to $2(1-\Phi(\frac{\ln(2.4226)}{\sigma}))= 0.05$?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you are doing in the 2nd part of the question. $R$ is the (unknown) true odds ratio (the parameter of interest), and you have calculated its estimate (the observed value of $\hat R$) in the first part.

For a large sample test, your test statistic for testing $H_0: R=1 \iff\ln (R)=0$ is

$$T=\frac{\ln (\hat R)}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_{0,0}}+ \frac{1}{n_{0,1}}+\frac{1}{n_{1,0}}+\frac{1}{n_{1,1}}}} \stackrel{d}\longrightarrow N(0,1) \quad,\text{ under }H_0$$

Based on given data, I get

$$\hat R=\frac{n_{0,0}\times n_{1,1}}{n_{0,1}\times n_{1,0}}=\frac{245\times 367}{218\times 170}\approx 2.42620 \implies \ln (\hat R)\approx 0.88633$$

And

$$\frac{1}{n_{0,0}}+ \frac{1}{n_{0,1}}+\frac{1}{n_{1,0}}+\frac{1}{n_{1,1}}=\frac1{245}+\frac1{218}+\frac1{170}+\frac1{367} \approx 0.01727$$

So find the observed value of $T$ and draw your conclusion, either using p-value or standard normal tables. The alternative hypothesis is presumably $H_1: \ln R\ne 0$.